# How to create a list of all possible lists satisfying a certain condition?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm currently trying to do project Euler problem 18 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=18), using the 'brute force' method to check all possible paths. I've just been trying the smaller, 'model' triangle so far.
I was using list comprehension to create a list of lists where the inner lists would contain the indices for that line, for example:

```
lst = [[a,b,c,d] for a in [0] for b in [0,1] for c in [0,1,2] for d in 
[0,1,2,3] if b == a or b == a + 1 if c == b or c == b + 1 if d == c or d == 
c + 1]
```

This gives me the list of lists I want, namely:

```
[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,2],[0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,2],[0,1,2,2],
[0,1,2,3]]
```

Note: the if conditions ensure that it only moves to adjacent numbers in the next row of the triangle, so that

```
lst[i][j] = lst[i][j-1] or lst[i][j] = lst[i][j]-1
```

After I got to this point, I intended that for each of the inner lists, I would take the numbers associated with those indices (so [0,0,0,0] would be 3,7,2,8) and sum over them, and this way get all of the possible sums, then take the maximum of those.

The problem is that if I were to scale this up to the big triangle I'd have fifteen 'for's and 'if's in my list comprehension. It seems like there must be an easier way! I'm pretty new to Python so hopefully there's some obvious feature I can make use of that I've missed so far!

Comment: You may want to look at `dynamic programming` algorithms to make computation more efficient.

Comment: I did some research in to dynamic programming, but I wanted to try out solving it using brute force first.

Answer (score 0):

What an interesting question! Here is a simple brute force approach, note the use of itertools to generate all the combinations, and then ruling out all the cases where successive row indices differ by more than one.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

# Here is the input triangle
tri = np.array([[3],[7,4],[2,4,6],[8,5,9,3]])
indices = np.array([range(len(i)) for i in tri])

# Generate all the possible combinations
indexCombs = list(itertools.product(*indices))

# Generate the difference between indices in successive rows for each combination
diffCombs = [np.array(i[1:]) - np.array(i[:-1]) for i in indexCombs]

# The only combinations that are valid are when successive row indices differ by 1 or 0
validCombs = [indexCombs[i] for i in range(len(indexCombs)) if np.all(diffCombs[i]**2<=1)]

# Now get the actual values from the triangle for each row combination
valueCombs = [[tri[i][j[i]] for i in range(len(tri))] for j in validCombs]

# Find the sum for each combination
sums = np.sum(valueCombs, axis=1)

# Print the information pertaining to the largest sum
print 'Highest sum: {0}'.format(sums.max())
print 'Combination: {0}'.format(valueCombs[sums.argmax()])
print 'Row indices: {0}'.format(indexCombs[sums.argmax()])
```

The output is:

> Highest sum: 23
>
> Combination: [3, 7, 4, 9]
>
> Row indices: (0, 0, 1, 0)

Unfortunately this is hugely intensive computationally, so it won't work with the large triangle - but there are definitely some concepts and tools that you could extend to try get it to work!

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely be looking up itertools and numpy - I'm sure they'll come in handy.

Yeah, my main problem was with scaling it up to the bigger triangle as there are so many possibilities it just takes ages to run!